# Error getting WsnNameService properties while connecting to EJB websphere

Tags: websphere, ejb, websphere-8, thin-client

I am trying to access EJB websphere and using below dependency to have the connectivity.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.orb</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
Log Error: Exception  caught: javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591  completed: No]
```

Can anyone update what configuration I am missing here. My code is able to create initial context but while looking up for JNDI path it is failing with above error.

Analysis- Checked the connectivity to the websphere server with telnet - Connectivity is working fine.

2. Verified the server path it is correct.
3. server is running at version 8.5

Anything other than this which can help me to trouble shoot this issue. I am stucked here from very long.

Comment: Have you look at this - https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/orgomgcorbatransient-initial-and-forwarded-ior-inaccessible-after-migration-version-8 ? Probably your server is requiring SSL connection and your client is not correctly set up for that.
Where your client is running? in server or in stand alone java app? 
Try to switch to supported ssl in CSI settings or setup ssl in client correctly, check this - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=applications-running-thin-client-enterprise-javabeans-ejb

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am looking into docs that you have shared. my client is running on one of my kubernetes pod. Regarding ssl settings from server side I changed Transport property from "SSL-required" to "SSL-supported". I can see in the article they are asking to set Java arguments for ssl.client.props and sas.client.props. So do I have to give the server path for these two files or we have to move this files to client location too?

Comment: if you set it to SSL-supported you dont need these ssl files, so check if it works that way. If you need ssl, probably the easiest would be to pack all that to your app image.

Comment: I did tried with SSL-Supported at server level but it is still failing with available error. Any other way I can debug the issue? @Gas

Comment: Try your app locally, without K8s as maybe there is no network path. Also try ping/curl WAS host:port from inside of your container to test connectivity. Did you notice any connections attempts in the WAS logs? Are you using correct port?